# How to set value to a hidden property with a button?

Tags: javascript

I have the following files:

view.jsp

```
<@ page import=...
<bean:define id="mForm" name="myForm" type="MyForm"/>
<html:form action="MyFoo" method="post" styleId="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<html:hidden property="boo"/>
<input type="button" value="Press me" onclick="javascript:changeBoo()"/> 
</html:form>
```

MyForm.java

```
class MyForm {
    private boolean boo;
    public void setBoo(boolean boo){
        this.boo = boo;
    }
    public boolean getBoo(){
        return this.boo;
    }
}
```

MyFooAction.java

```
public class MyFooAction extends BaseAction {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        ActionForward aForward = null;
        String forward = "success";

        try {
            MyForm myForm = (MyForm) form;
            String boo = (String)request.getParameter("boo");
            if(boo.equals("true")){
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>DONE");
            }
            else {
                //some code here
            }
            aForward = mapping.findForward(forward);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return aForward;
    }
}
```

The question is how to implement `changeBoo()` in Javascript in order to change the value of `boo` and to invoke `MyFooAction` with correct value of `boo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change your button to `type="submit"`.  That will take care of submitting the form for you.  Notice how `changeBoo()` now returns a value for your onclick attribute.  This will submit the form if your function returns `true`.

Also, you'll need to add an `id` attribute to your hidden field so that you can easily get a reference to it from javascript:

```
<html:hidden property="boo" id="booId" />
<input type="submit" value="Press me" onclick="return changeBoo();"/>
```

Then it's just a matter of creating the javascript function:

```
function changeBoo(){  
   var boo = document.getElementById('booId');    
   boo.value = 'The new value';
   return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks :) But id is not necessary. Without it, everything is working fine.
Error: Attribute: id is not a valid attribute name

Answer (score 1):

**PS** On your `<html:form>...</html:form>`, make sure you have a way to submit a form. This is usually done by adding `<html:submit>`.

Now, to come back to your question, your Javascript function will be like this (*assuming that your `ActionForm` name specified on struts-config.xml is "myForm"*).

```
fumction changeBoo() {
  var boo = document.myForm.boo;
  if ("true" == boo.value.toLowerCase() || "yes" == boo.value.toLowerCase() || "1" == boo.value.toLowerCase()) {
     boo.value = "false";
  } else {
     boo.value = "true";
  }
}
```

Bear in mind that Struts converts boolean values to "true" or "false", "yes" or "no", "0" or "1".